# Replace multiple lines with regex

Tags: python, regex

Given the following text, I want to remove everything in `data_augmentation_options{..}`

i.e., input is :

```
  batch_size: 4
  num_steps: 30
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 0
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 2
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 1
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 4
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 3
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 6
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 5
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 8
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 7
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 10
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 9
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 12
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 11
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 14
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 13
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 16
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 15
    }
  }

  data_augmentation_options {
    random_crop_image {
      min_aspect_ratio: 0.5
      max_aspect_ratio: 1.7
      random_coef: 0.25
    }
  }
```

expected output is:

```
  batch_size: 4
  num_steps: 30
```

I tried

```
s='''
      batch_size: 4
      num_steps: 30
      data_augmentation_options {
        random_horizontal_flip {
          keypoint_flip_permutation: 0
          keypoint_flip_permutation: 2
          keypoint_flip_permutation: 1
          keypoint_flip_permutation: 4
          keypoint_flip_permutation: 3
          keypoint_flip_permutation: 6
          keypoint_flip_permutation: 5
          keypoint_flip_permutation: 8
          keypoint_flip_permutation: 7
          keypoint_flip_permutation: 10
          keypoint_flip_permutation: 9
          keypoint_flip_permutation: 12
          keypoint_flip_permutation: 11
          keypoint_flip_permutation: 14
          keypoint_flip_permutation: 13
          keypoint_flip_permutation: 16
          keypoint_flip_permutation: 15
        }
      }
    
      data_augmentation_options {
        random_crop_image {
          min_aspect_ratio: 0.5
          max_aspect_ratio: 1.7
          random_coef: 0.25
        }
      }
'''
print(re.sub('data_augmentation_options \{*\}','',s,flags=re.S))
```

It does not seem to work, what's the right way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than deleting what you don't want you could capture what you do want:

```
>>> re.findall(r'batch_size: *\d+|num_steps: *\d+',s)
['batch_size: 4', 'num_steps: 30']
```

Or if you want to capture the leading spaces:

```
>>> re.findall(r'^[ \t]*(?:batch_size:|num_steps:)[ \t]*\d+',s, flags=re.M)
['\t\t\tbatch_size: 4', '\t\t\tnum_steps: 30']
```

Then print the result:

```
>>> print('\n'.join(re.findall(r'^[ \t]*(?:batch_size:|num_steps:)[ \t]*\d+',s, flags=re.M))
        batch_size: 4
        num_steps: 30
```

If you want to use `re.sub` you can use a conflicted character class that will match any and all characters after the match. A conflicted character class is something like `[\s\S]` which is a space or non-space character:

```
>>> re.sub(r'data_augmentation_options[\s\S]*','',s)

        batch_size: 4
        num_steps: 30
```

Perhaps even easier is to just use Python's [str.partition](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) with the string that you want to use as a separator:

```
>>> s.partition('data_augmentation_options')[0]

        batch_size: 4
        num_steps: 30
```

Comment: Thanks, could you help looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65479947/replace-with-multi-line-regex

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
s = re.sub("\W+data_augmentation_options {(?:.|\n)*}", "", s).strip()
```