# Replace with multi line regex

Tags: python, regex

Given the following text, I want to remove everything in `data_augmentation_options{random_horizontal_flip {..}}`
(`...` means other text in the following)

i.e., input is :

```
  ...
  batch_size: 4
  num_steps: 30
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 0
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 2
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 1
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 4
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 3
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 6
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 5
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 8
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 7
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 10
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 9
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 12
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 11
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 14
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 13
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 16
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 15
    }
  }

  data_augmentation_options {
    random_crop_image {
      min_aspect_ratio: 0.5
      max_aspect_ratio: 1.7
      random_coef: 0.25
    }
  }

  ...
```

expected output is:

```
  ...
  batch_size: 4
  num_steps: 30

  data_augmentation_options {
    random_crop_image {
      min_aspect_ratio: 0.5
      max_aspect_ratio: 1.7
      random_coef: 0.25
    }
  }
  ...
```

I tried

```
s=''' ...
      batch_size: 4
      num_steps: 30
      data_augmentation_options {
        random_horizontal_flip {
          keypoint_flip_permutation: 0
          keypoint_flip_permutation: 2
          keypoint_flip_permutation: 1
          keypoint_flip_permutation: 4
          keypoint_flip_permutation: 3
          keypoint_flip_permutation: 6
          keypoint_flip_permutation: 5
          keypoint_flip_permutation: 8
          keypoint_flip_permutation: 7
          keypoint_flip_permutation: 10
          keypoint_flip_permutation: 9
          keypoint_flip_permutation: 12
          keypoint_flip_permutation: 11
          keypoint_flip_permutation: 14
          keypoint_flip_permutation: 13
          keypoint_flip_permutation: 16
          keypoint_flip_permutation: 15
        }
      }
    
      data_augmentation_options {
        random_crop_image {
          min_aspect_ratio: 0.5
          max_aspect_ratio: 1.7
          random_coef: 0.25
        }
      }
      ...
'''
print(re.sub('data_augmentation_options \{[\s]+random_horizontal_flip[\s]+\{[\s]+(keypoint_flip_permutation: \d[\s])+[\s]+\}[\s]+\}','',s,flags=re.S))
```

It does not seem to work, what's the right way to achieve this?

Comment: The string input looks like json, might be easier to load it as json, remove the data and then make it json again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only matching a sinlge line instead of all the lines.

You can repeat the lines for this format `keypoint_flip_permutation: \d+` and match the 2 closing curly's

**Note** that you don't need `re.S` as there is no dot in the pattern.

```
data_augmentation_options {\s+random_horizontal_flip\s+{(?:\s+keypoint_flip_permutation: \d+)+\s*}\s*}\s*
```

**Explanation**

- `data_augmentation_options {` Match literally
- `\s+random_horizontal_flip\s+` match the starting line
- `{` Match literally
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\s+keypoint_flip_permutation: \d+` Match the string string followed by 1+ digits
- `)+` Repeat 1+ times
- `\s*}` Match optional whitespace chars and `}`
- `\s*}` Match optional whitespace chars and `}`
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars

If you want to remove only the trailing newline, you can match `\r?\n` at the end instead of `\s*`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NAKZrN/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/PIQEnU)

for example

```
print(re.sub(r"data_augmentation_options {\s+random_horizontal_flip\s+{(?:\s+keypoint_flip_permutation: \d+)+\s*}\s*}\s*", "", s))
```

Comment: May I know what's the purpose of adding `?:`?

Comment: @william007 Using `(?:` means a non capturing group, so the `+` after it repeats it as a whole. I have made a small update to the explanation.

Comment: But looks like even if I omit `(?:` it works too, any advantages on including that?

Comment: @william007 If you remove the grouping part it does not match, see https://regex101.com/r/DV8NlA/1. You can make it a capturing group using `()` instead of `(?:)` But then you will capture the last iteration of the data in a group, which you don't need, see https://regex101.com/r/hQyc1S/1

Answer (score 0):

A few modification to your regex to become

```
data_augmentation_options {\s+random_horizontal_flip\s+{(\s+keypoint_flip_permutation:\s\d+\s)+\s+}\s+}
```

- replace `[\s]` by just `\s`, which is equivalent
- put the `\s+` inside the capture group `()`
- replace `\d` by `\d+` to match multi-digits numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lookahead to stop the deletion at the second pattern:

```
>>> re.sub(r'^[ \t]*data_augmentation_options[\s\S]+?(?=^[ \t]*data_augmentation_options)','\n\n',s, flags=re.M)

        batch_size: 4
        num_steps: 30
        

        data_augmentation_options {
            random_crop_image {
                min_aspect_ratio: 0.5
                max_aspect_ratio: 1.7
                random_coef: 0.25
            }
        }
```

The `(?=^[ \t]*data_augmentation_options)` is the lookahead.

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NZiMSL/2)